# Table radio button with br tag

Tags: html, css

I create quiz template. There are radio button. But I do not want Side by Side. I want one under the other.

why `<br/>` tag is does not work I do not understand.. Could you help me

**This is My code**

http://jsfiddle.net/yyw2A/

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <b>1)"Men are basically little piglets...Males are biologically driven to go out and hunt giraffes."</b>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr id="0">
    <td onmouseover="checkSelect(this)" onmouseout="setBGDefault(this)" onclick="applySelect(this,0)"><input type="radio" name=que_1 value="1" />Newt Gingrich</td>
<br>
<td onmouseover="checkSelect(this)" onmouseout="setBGDefault(this)" onclick="applySelect(this,1)"><input type="radio" name=que_1 value="0" />Dwight Schrute</td>
<br>
<td onmouseover="checkSelect(this)" onmouseout="setBGDefault(this)" onclick="applySelect(this,1)"><input type="radio" name=que_1 value="0" />Dwight Schrute</td>
<br>
<td onmouseover="checkSelect(this)" onmouseout="setBGDefault(this)" onclick="applySelect(this,1)"><input type="radio" name=que_1 value="0" />Dwight Schrute</td>
<br>
</tr>

<tr id="correct" style="display:none">
  <td colspan="2">Correct! This is from a controversial lecture on the military that Gingrich delivered while teaching at Reinhardt College. He also said that "females have biological problems staying in a ditch for thirty days because they get infections and they don't have upper body strength," when referring to women participating in combat missions.</td>
</tr>

<tr id="wrong" style="display:none;">
     <td colspan="2">Doh, wrong. This is from a controversial lecture on the military that Gingrich delivered while teaching at Reinhardt College. He also said that "females have biological problems staying in a ditch for thirty days because they get infections and they don't have upper body strength," when referring to women participating in combat missions.</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `<br>` is invalid as a direct descendant of `<tr>` try placing all of your checkboxes in one `<td>` then using `<br>` after each.

Comment: try putting <br> tag inside td as <br></td>.

Comment: Sory my english is bad.. I understand you said do one <td> but all td have js class which have different issue.

Comment: @duygu Wrap it in another div or label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `br` element isn't a valid child of `tr` elements. If you want all your checkboxes on different lines, simply add them all to the same `td` element and wrap each `input` within a `label`:

```
<td ...>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name=que_1 value="1" />
        Newt Gingrich<br>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name=que_1 value="0" />
        Dwight Schrute<br>
    </label>
    ...
</td>
```

You'll then want to add your mouse events to each `label` instead of each `td` element:

```
<label onmouseover="checkSelect(this)"
       onmouseout="setBGDefault(this)"
       onclick="applySelect(this,0)">
    ...
</label>
```

You could also drop the `br` completely with a bit of CSS:

```css
td label {
    display:block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yyw2A/1/).

Comment: @duygu that's because you've not actually done what my answer suggests you should do. `td` elements aren't valid children of `label` elements, and I've provided a working JSFiddle demo in my answer already.

Comment: hımm ok ı am trying again.. I see your fiddle just now sory. I am trying agaib

Comment: yes it do side by side but it does not show  "<td colspan="2">Correct! This is from a controversial"

Comment: but your answer true I have to design my js again :((

Answer (score 0):

why you use Table for each radio button. you can use `ul` and in each `li` put your radio button like this:

```
<ul id='0'>
   <lionmouseover="checkSelect(this)" onmouseout="setBGDefault(this)" onclick="applySelect(this,0)"><input type="radio" name=que_1 value="1" />Newt Gingrich </li>
     .
     .
     .
</ul>
```

**if you have to use `table`** you can put all radio button in one `td` and put `br` tag after them.

**or**

put any radio button in one `tr` tag

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are using a table.
Your radio buttons are all in  tag, meaning that each radio button is part of the column.It will only collapse unless you put each input in a tr tag like so:

```
<tr><td><input id="answer_1" type="radio" /><label for="answer_1">Answer 1</label></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="answer_2" type="radio" /><label for="answer_2">Answer 2</label></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="answer_3" type="radio" /><label for="answer_3">Answer 3</label></td></tr>
```

My war is to take out the table completely and do this instead:

```
<input id="answer_1" type="radio" /><label for="answer_1">Answer 1</label><br>
<input id="answer_2" type="radio" /><label for="answer_2">Answer 2</label><br>
<input id="answer_3" type="radio" /><label for="answer_">Answer 3</label><br>
```

Label is used to label inputs such as checkboxes and radio. This is good for screenreaders and also if you click on the text it will check the radio button. Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8DLXw/

Comment: but this fiddle is same to my fiddle.. :( and I used label but it is not work

Comment: I have edited my post and changed the jsfiddle, sorry about that

Comment: I am checking...but you did not use my class name id names :(( it is very hard to convert it I am trying